# Android Navigation and Data Storage

Tags: android, sql, xml, performance, sqlite

I've got a project for Android that I'm working on that involves creating Navigation for a Book.  I've chosen the Bible, and have run into some tough questions.

Here is my question:
**Should I Use SQL or XML to store my Navigational Data?**

Each Volume has a list of Books, each Book has a list of Chapters, and each Chapter has a list of Verses.  I've got a Sqlite Database of the Verses, with the Primary Key as the VerseId, but am trying to figure out the best way to build the navigation.

My current plan is to use XML to structure the Books and the Chapters separately, but am not sure whether to do this or to use several SQL Statements.

Here is an example of my ChapterXML

```
<ChapterData xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<chapter>
    <chapterId>1</chapterId>
    <volumeId>1</volumeId>
    <bookId>1</bookId>
    <bookTitle>Genesis</bookTitle>
    <chapterNumber>1</chapterNumber>
    <verseCount>31</verseCount>
    <minVerseId>1</minVerseId>
</chapter>
<chapter>
    <chapterId>2</chapterId>
    <volumeId>1</volumeId>
    <bookId>1</bookId>
    <bookTitle>Genesis</bookTitle>
    <chapterNumber>2</chapterNumber>
    <verseCount>25</verseCount>
    <minVerseId>32</minVerseId>
</chapter>
<chapter>
    <chapterId>3</chapterId>
    <volumeId>1</volumeId>
    <bookId>1</bookId>
    <bookTitle>Genesis</bookTitle>
    <chapterNumber>3</chapterNumber>
    <verseCount>24</verseCount>
    <minVerseId>57</minVerseId>
</chapter>
...
</ChapterData>
```

Here is my BookXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookData>
<book>
   <bookName>Genesis</bookName>
   <numChapters>50</numChapters>
   <firstVerseId>1</firstVerseId>
</book>
<book>
   <bookName>Exodus</bookName>
   <numChapters>40</numChapters>
   <firstVerseId>51</firstVerseId>
</book>
<book>
   <bookName>Leviticus</bookName>
   <numChapters>27</numChapters>
   <firstVerseId>91</firstVerseId>
</book>
...
</BookData>
```

When a user clicks on a book, it will go to the XML BookData to see how many chapters there are, then when the user selects a chapter, then it will go to the Chapter XML to see how many verses there are, and when they click on a Verse, it will find the firstVerseId, add it's position in the list to get the final VerseId, and then SQL SELECT the verse from that Id.

Is this the best way to go about it?  Or should I use SQL all the way?

Comment: Are you trying to import this data dynamically ? Or include it in the assets ? Or is this data generated by the user then stored locally ?

Comment: Dynamically.  As in, when the App is fired up, this XML would be read by a function in the onCreate or onStart function and from there, the navigation would be created.

Comment: Is the data shipped with the app or read from a server ? Thats what I mean by dynamic

Comment: Shipped with the app.  Now I understand.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Why not use json ? If you really dont want to use sql